# IcCube - refresh schema without reloading of data

Tags: iccube

In the default perspective of my cube I renamed the dimension, hide one, and changed default member. For example something like this:

```
default [Geography].[Geo].[City].[Madrid]
-[Time]
rename [Geography].[Geo] as [Location]
```

If I want to see the changes in the Excel Pivot Table I need to redeploy and reload the schema, but as I understand while loading schema, data from underlying tables are also reloaded. Is it possible to avoid reloading of data, and at the same time to see this changes in the cube?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perspectives cannot be defined dynamically so you'll have to reload the schema.

Nevertheless, you could setup an offline snapshost ([www](https://www.iccube.com/support/documentation/user_guide/using/offline_cubes.php)) to be able to reload faster your schema.

Hope that helps.